# Changing symbol with different pattern in a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

I have a text file. It is a big text file and This file contains some patterns like the following:

```
(1), (3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

...and like this,

```
(Fig1) (Fig1,Fig2), (Table-1, Table-2) etc.
```

I want the output like this

```
[1], [3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], (Fig1) (Fig1,Fig2), (Table-1, Table-2)
```

I mean I only want to change the () into [] which contains only numbers. 
Please help me

Comment: Is it OK to also subtitute things like `()`, `(,,)`, `(,1,)`? When you say _numbers_, is it only positive decimal integer numbers like in your sample or can it be things like `-1`, `1.2`, `1e9`, `0x12`... ? Can we assume that parenthesis won't be nested (no `("Fig(1,2)", "Fig3")` for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/(\([0-9,]*\))/[\1]/g' filename.txt
```

`[0-9,]*` is a regular expression matching any number of digits and commas. I enclosed it in `\(\)` so I could reuse it in the replacement string as `\1`. The simple parenthesis without backslashes stand for themselves. They get replaced by the `[]` (which don't have a special meaning in the replacement string).

Answer (score 1):

#### Python 3 script solution

The script below is an explicit more "manual" solution that doesn't use regular expressions, but does the job with a few extra considerations. The key to its operation is that the script opens for reading whatever file we've provided on command-line, iterates over each character in each line, seeking to find brackets. If we see brackets, we record whatever is inside, and after throwing away commas we decide if that's a numerical string or not. If it is a numerical string - the recorded items go into list of words, which is later rebuild into a line using `.join()` function with `", "` as separator. Fairly straight-forward.

```py
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        # we're going to store everything into list of words
        # and record individual characters into 'item' string
        # and rebuild everything as we go.
        words = []
        item_found = False
        item = ""
        counter = 0
        for char in line:
            # if we see ( or [ we start recording chars
            # difference is that [ means item already been edited
            # so no need to do anything - just put it into words list
            # as is
            if char == "(" or char == "[":
                item_found = True
                counter = counter + 1
                continue

            if char == ")":
                item_found = False
                if item.replace(",","").isdigit():
                   words.append("[" + item + "]")
                else:
                   words.append("("+item+")")
                item = ""

            if char == "]":
              item_found = False
              item = item + char
              words.append("[" + item) 
              item = ""

            if item_found:
                item = item + char

        # if we didn't see any open brackets or no closing brackets
        # just print the line as is - otherwise give us the altered one
        if counter == 0 or item_found:
            print(line.strip())
        else:
            print(", ".join(words))
```

#### Test run:

I took liberty with OP's input to include extra 2 lines that include couple different test cases.

```
$ # original input file
$ cat input.txt
(1), (3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), (Fig1) (Fig1,Fig2), (Table-1, Table-2)
(table-25),[1,2,3],(figure-35)
(figure-1),(figure-2)
$ # script output 
$ ./change_brackets.py input.txt                                                          
[1], [3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], (Fig1), (Fig1,Fig2), (Table-1, Table-2)
(table-25), [1,2,3], (figure-35)
(figure-1), (figure-2)
```

With 40,000 lines of text it performs fairly quick:

```
$ wc -l big_input.txt                                                                     
40000 big_input.txt
$ time ./change_brackets.py big_input.txt  > /dev/null                                    
    0m01.64s real     0m01.60s user     0m00.01s system
```

Possible suggestion for improvement ( and to [address one of the things that Stephane has mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364570/changing-symbol-with-different-pattern-in-a-text-file/364576?noredirect=1#comment647173_364570) ) is to change `if item.replace(",","").isdigit()` line into `if item.replace(",","").replace(".","").isdigit()`. This will allow us to deal with floating point numbers (such as 3.1415) as well.

Lengthy ? Yes. Explicit ? Yes. Works ? Well, yes.

Comment: What happend to the third item of the second line of your output?

Comment: @Philippos  Thanks for pointing that out. The issue was that I forgot to clear the `item` variable in the 3rd if statement, the `if car == "]"` was missing `item = ""` at the end. Fixed that already.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/[(](([0-9]+,?)+)[)]/[\1]/g'

sed -e 's/(\(\([0-9]\{1,\},\{0,\}\)\{1,\}\))/[\1]/g'
```

We are looking for the regex [0-9]+,? occurring at least once and at the same time bounded by ( and ) brackets. The outer brackets are changed to [ ] on success.

The second sed statement is the POSIXly version of the above.